# Dealing with "none" responses in discrete choice models

Tags: r, multinomial-logit

I have data which consists of respondents' answers to a question on political party identification, as well as other covariates for the respondents such as income, age, etc. Respondents are asked to select which party they identify with from a list, and one of the options is "none". I also have data for choice characteristics of all of the listed parties (e.g. position on an economic "left/right" scale), but obviously not for the "none" option. I'm trying to use the `mclogit` package in R (https://www.elff.eu/software/mclogit/) to model party identification as a function of both the various choice characteristics of the parties and the other respondent covariates. I could just drop all the respondents who don't identify with a party, but I'm worried that throwing away data could lead to biased estimates and/or poor model fit. How can I handle "none" responses in a discrete choice model?

Comment: Why do you feel that 'None' provides no information?

Comment: @BruceET I didn't say a "none" response provides no information in theory, I just don't have any data on the choice characteristics of a "none" response like I do for the parties each respondent can choose from. "None" obviously doesn't have a particular economic left/right score associated with it, for example, because the left/right score is computed based on party manifesto documents (for reference, I'm using this database for party characteristics: https://manifesto-project.wzb.eu/).

Comment: Dropping the nones means that your subsequent inferences are no longer on the whole population, but on the population of respondents who identify with a party. That seems appropriate when you want to study left-right orientation.

Comment: @RussLenth This is helpful. Thank you